# While Import python. ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, archlinux

I have tried many solutions like installing from different sources official google link `Google.api...`, `pypi` and also building from git repo.

But every time I face the same problem `ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0:`

OS: `Linux Arch` tensorflow: `tensorflow-gpu` version`1.5`

Nvidia: `Cuda 9.1 and Cudnn 7.0.5`

> Note: tensorflow cpu is working fine

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.


for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: have you considered using docker/nvidia-docker? i wrote an article about installing the gpu version of tensor flow on arch linux with docker [here](http://briancaffey.github.io/2017/11/19/tensorflow-gpu-setup-with-docker-on-arch-linux.html). what gpu are you using?

Comment: Yes just considering it. because now there is no possible solution left to be considered.
gpu: **NVIDIA NVS 5200M**
Btw nice Article

Comment: thanks yes I spent several hours trying every other solution with no success then docker worked on my first try. Hope you can get it working

Answer (score 5):

Your error message indicates that Tensorflow is looking for CUDA 9.0, while the default download is CUDA 9.1. I suggest down-reviving to CUDA 9.0. I just installed TF prebuilt binaries with CUDA 9.0 and the corresponding cudnn 7.05 and everything ran fine. From [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15656) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15140) it seems there are some issues with CUDA 9.1 that are still be to be worked out.

Note also that currently the [TF 1.5 install guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/install/install_linux) seems to be incorrect since it specifies CUDA 8.0 and cudnn 6.0 for the prebuilt TF while [the release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) specify cuda 9 and cudnn 7

Comment: i hit the same issue recently when trying to run TF 1.5 with CUDA9.1 downgrading to CUDA 9.0 did the trick.